# Translation of "weiterwandern"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I found in some German newspaper word *weitergewandert* and I think it is present perfect of *weiterwandern*, but I cannot find a translation.

What would be an appropriate translation?

Comment: To be precise: it is a form of "weiterwandern", not "weiterwanderen". I've edited your post accordingly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, it simply means "walked on" or "marched on", continuing the course already started, implying that the suject did not stop where it would have been expected.

It is a separable verb meaning that the present tense would be "weiter wandern".

A typical use is for the sun or moon, which simply continue to advance across the sky (despite the horrors that happen on earth and that should have stopped even those stellar objects).

Answer (score 0):

*Weiter wandern* (with space) means go on with wandering.
*Weiterwandern* (without space) means to wander to the next place.

Comment: Can you please give an explantation why or give a reference for this claim.